# What is a proper way to create class instance from KType

Tags: reflection, jvm, kotlin

I have two classes which might look like this

```
class MyClass {
    var myProperty: AnotherClass?
}

class AnotherClass {

}
```

Through reflection I iterate the properties of MyClass and when I find a `KMutableProperty<*>` which is null I want to create an instance of that class. Right now I'm doing something like this

```
val instance = MyClass()
val property = MyClass::myProperty
var subInstance = it.getter.call(instance)
if (subInstance == null) {
    it.setter.call(instance, property.returnType.jvmErasure.createInstance())
}
```

but this seems like a terrible hack that needs to know internals and use Java magic instead of being pure Kotlin, is there a *proper* way to do what I want? Or is this the proper way?

Comment: Is your goal specifically to initialize all null properties with calls to the default, no parameter constructors of the classes you need in those places?

Comment: That's right, all of them will be POJO (POKO?) classes

Comment: I believe that there isn't currently a way to do this without making the `jvmErasure` call right now. I suppose that makes it the proper way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `(property.returnType.classifier as KClass).createInstance()` instead.